# How does the Bacon number work exactly?

Tags: credits, kevin-bacon

There is this commonly known [meme about actors working together with Kevin Bacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon) and the associated "Bacon number" defining the degree of separation an actor has from Kevin Bacon based on collaborative works. But how does it work exactly?

If I was an *extra* in a movie with Kevin Bacon, in the same scene as Kevin Bacon but they never listed me in the credits on IMDB, can I claim a Bacon number or does it not count? I don't think it counts something like *meeting* Kevin Bacon, just acting in movies counts and not even being the director of a Kevin Bacon movie will count as a Bacon number of 1 since only *actors* count.

With this interpretation, can I claim a Bacon number of 4 if I was an extra in the same scene in a feature movie with Jon Skolmen who has Bacon number of 3?

**Is it safe to say that my Bacon number is limited to, and at most 4?**

Comment: While you're working out your Bacon number, you might also want to spend a few minutes getting IMDB to update your credits history; http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?uncreditedcredits

Comment: If I hypothetically was an extra in a movie, do I actually have a right to a credit? I'm visible for about 7 or 10 seconds. I read the imdb doc and I don't think I can claim a credit if this is my only credit and as an extra.

Comment: Theoretically yes. The rules are slightly more flexible for older films (where fewer extras were credited) but the general principle is that you have to be  ***"identifiable and featured on-screen in the final released cut of the title"*** and that you may be asked to "***provide photos/stills/screen grabs to verify that you are featured."***. If it's your sole credit you'll really struggle though...

Comment: I was an extra in the hotel check-in scene in the movie snow roller (1985) with Jon Skolmen. I think that I'm the kid to the right when the lady at the hotel counter speaks and Jon Skolmen and Lasse Åberg are standing with me and my older sister (filmed in Verbier). I don't exclude that I was cut out but I'm sure that I saw the scene when I saw the movie last time (very long time ago). I'm going to locate the scene now. I don't have a name and I didn't have a line but I might have been cut out for some reason.

Comment: I'm still in the movie. At 00:10:48 I am clearly visible in the movie for several seconds. Ergo: my bacon number is at most 4.

Comment: That being the case, the actor [Björn Granath](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090115/) (who also appeared in Snowroller)  has a [Bacon number of 2](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Bj%C3%B6rn+Granath+bacon+number), making your Bacon number 3.

Comment: Fascinating! Irritating that TV doesn't count.. If it did my Bacon number would be 3, movies only it's *Infinity* :-( [I only count it if I had a line, I've never put SA work on my IMDB page]

Comment: @Tetsujin What does "SA work" mean? Is it being an extra? In my case I might have a bacon number anyway if I choose a different footage than snow roller (1985).

Comment: Sorry, SA = Supporting Artist, the new 'PC' term for 'extra'. I've an audition Tuesday for a part alongside Tom Hardy... but again it's TV, so no bacon even if I'm in the whole series... ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you. Good luck on Tuesday! I was also uncredited sound technician for a TV episode that was broadcast several times since 1999. I might claim 2 imdb credits for 1. sound technician (not "SA work" since I was the only technician) and the extra I did in 1985.

Comment: Tip: To quickly find someone's bacon number, Google "bacon number <name>", eg bacon number John Wayne

Comment: I read that politicians can have a bacon number. Can you reject your own bacon number if you have a bacon number because somebody included you in a documentary for example: known criminals who were in the same documentary as a famous person can have a bacon number just because they were real world villains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The creators of the Kevin Bacon game elaborated on the major rules of the game in their book "[Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0452278449)". These have been replicated in a number of books including "[Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon: The Complete Guide to the Movie Trivia Game](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YZyqXZ_3sEwC&pg=PT1381&lpg=PT1381&dq=%22Six%20Degrees%20of%20Kevin%20Bacon%22%20and%20torrent&source=bl&ots=fsufCh4Cy7&sig=ur26bnGEDa8ukjlTEHinlZS2lCw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=movie%20trivia%20game&f=false)"

> **HOW THIS GAME WORKS**
>
> Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon is a movie trivia game where one person who
> has been in at least one film is named. Usually (but not always) this
> is an actor or actress, but anyone appearing in a film can be named.
> This person is then linked to Kevin Bacon using as few films as
> possible. However, non-actors and non-actresses that have been in
> films, people like Donald Trump and Larry King, usually can be linked
> (Donald Trump/54/Neve Campbell/WT/KB Larry King/Mad City/Dustin
> Hoffman/SL/KB]
>
> Crew members of films don't count unless they also
> appear in the film. No animals can be used either, Homo sapiens only.
>
> Appearance in a film by archival footage does not count for game
> purposes but **extras and people who only do voiceover work in a film do
> count.** Links are only allowed using films, no made-for-TV movies, no
> TV series, no straight-to-video releases, and no video games are
> allowed. Actors and actresses who have only appeared on stage, TV
> and/or straight-to-video releases and were never in a film cannot be
> linked.

I've highlighted the relevant passage. Since you were hypothetically an *extra* in a film starring Bacon, your 'Bacon number' would be 1. Anyone starring in a film alongside you would have a 'Bacon number' of 2.

By comparison, Oliver Stone's 'Bacon number' is 3 since directing (e.g. being part of the crew for) a Bacon movie wouldn't make him a 1, nor would starring alongside him in the **made-for-TV** film '[Oliver Stone: Inside Out](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0143781/)' since it wasn't a feature film. His closest brush is through his work as an extra on the film 'Dave' alongside Sigourney Weaver (whose 'Bacon number' is [2](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sigourney%20weaver%20bacon%20number))

Comment: All of the above being said, if you're looking to *prove* your Bacon number, then a missing IMDB credit can't possibly help you.